# What is the relation between un-checking the "Allow members to share" option and having the "Restricted Link" option inside the "Get Link" popup

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, document, share

I can not understand what is the relation between these 2 options:-

1. Now if inside my SharePoint Online site collection settings >> Access Request Settings >> i un-check the "allow members to share", as follow:-

[image]

2. then if any user member or even site owner user, click on "Get Link" for a file, then the only option for the link type will be "Restricted link" and the options will be disabled, as follow:-

[image]

3. while if i check the "allow members to share" checkboxes, then the options for the link type will be enabled as follow:-

[image]

so my questions are:-

1. what is the relation between the "allow members to share" checkbox and the link type options inside the Get Link popup? as the "allow members to share" should only be related to allowing non-admin users to directly share files, without getting admin approval.
2. now if we check the "allow members to share" checkboxes, this will result in a weird behavior, that when users click on "Get Link" the file will automatically have unique permission. so my question is can i still allow members to share files, while prevent files from having unique permission if users click on "Get Link"??

Answer (score 3):

Allow members to share the site and individual files and folders. If this box is checked – that will allow users to share individual files with people outside of the security groups/site. So essentially, any user who has access to the site will be able to click on Share document and share file with someone outside of the department. This also creates somewhat of a nightmare as you might end up with hundreds of documents, each with its unique security/sharing. Not a good thing for site performance and maintenance reasons.

Restricted Link only work if the user already has access to that site collection (or has permissions on the item or list level). Everyone else will get an access denied page.

So if you have already enable  "allow members to share" , only restricted link is there and it is read-only .

A good blog for you reference : https://sharepointmaven.com/share-vs-get-link-sharepoint-onedrive/

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but i think this sentence is not accurate  `So if you have already enable "allow members to share" , only restricted link is there and it is read-only . ` .. because if i enable "allow members to share" checkbox, then users will have the option to select different link type, and the "restricted link" will not be in read only,, is this correct?

Comment: can you please advice on my above comment?

Comment: can you advice on my above comments?